# Finding Build failure cause via ant target

Tags: ant, build.xml

Hello I am very new to programming and ant, but wanted to learn and need some help from available Gurus.

At the moment we have build system and it builds on every code check-in, but many times there are build failures.

I wanted to know if there is any way to create ant target by which it can send out email notification to the person who broke the build with the error?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment we have build system and it builds on every code check-in

What system is this?

Normally, this functionality would be found in your continuous integration system, something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo), [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), or [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)

Comment: thanks for the response jgritty, yeah we are using Go-build and I eventually figured out from the settings to send emails on failure, success, blocked etc. The only challenging part is to send email notification to the person who broke the build including the error in email via some automated way.

Answer (score 0):

For sending mail use [ant mail logger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#MailLogger).
To work out who broke the build depends upon your version control system => cvs, svn, git .. etc.
Each of that tools provides it's specific ways to detect the person that did the checkin, commit, push ..
IMO it's better to send the mail to a list of recipients that are responsible for the application than to one person only - which may be out of office .. etc.

Comment: thanks Rebse, actually I am looking for a way to send automated notification on build failure explicitly to the person who broke the build with the error log.